# gsub only in part of string

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I have a string `s` and I want to replace all `"123"`'s with `"abcd"`'s, **but only in the first 50 characters**.

I know can do

```
s[0,50] = s[0,50].gsub("123", "abcd")
```

But is there a way to do it directly on `s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look behinds will be helpful in such situations

The regex can look like:

```
/(?<!.{50})123/
```

- Negative look behind. Ensures that the `123` is not preceded by `50` characters

[**Regex Demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/sE2sC5/2)

**Usage**

```
string.gsub(/(?<!.{50})123/, "abc")
```

**Test**

```
print "1234567890123".gsub(/(?<!.{10})123/, "abc") # I was bit lazy that I                     
                                                   # checked only for 10 characters
=> abc4567890123
```